# Styling a list in very deeply nested DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage located at http://www.richmindonline.com/doggy/index.html.  I'm having trouble styling a single list near the middle of the page.  I'm wanting to add `{list-style-type:disc;}` as a style, but it's not working. The list in which I want styles applied is located under the "Welcome" paragraph and it's specifically under the 1st of 4 boxes labeled "news".  The first item of the list is "Link to News Story".  I tried using Firefox to find the element, but even when I'm being very specific, the styles are not changing.

Any help would be appreciated.  HTML is listed below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Go-to Guide For Pets</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="maxheight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body  id="page1" onload="new ElementMaxHeight(); ">
<div class="main">
<div id="header">
    <ul class="ul1">
        <li><a href="index.html">Welcome</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="information.html">Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="funhouse.html">Funhouse</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="indent-block">
            <img alt="" src="images/title1.gif" /><br />
            <p><strong>Special program for your dog</strong></p>
            <ul class="ul">
                <li><a href="#">Nulla dui. Fusce feugiat mal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Esuada odio. scing elitauris </a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Fermentum dictum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/button.gif" class="button" /></a>
  </div>
    <div class="indent">
        <a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="images/logo.gif" class="logo" /></a><br />
        <a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="images/img.jpg" /></a><br />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">      
    <div class="indent-main">
        <div class="indent">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <div class="indent-col1">
                        <h1 class="title">Welcome</h1>
                        <p class="p1">Welcome Pet Lovers! &nbsp;Here you'll find just what you're looking for - with a big extra bonus: FUN! &nbsp;Sure, you could buy that catnip or dog toy anywhere else, but here at the Go-To Guide, we are SERIOUSLY committed to making you SMILE. &nbsp;Maybe even LAUGH!</p>
                      <div class="box">
                            <div class="border-top">
                                <div class="border-bottom">
                                    <div class="corner-top-right">
                                        <div class="corner-top-left">
                                            <div class="corner-bottom-left">
                                                <div class="corner-bottom-right"> 
                                                    <div class="indent-box">
                                                        <div class="container">
                                                          <div class="col-3">
                                                                <img alt="" src="images/1page_img1.jpg" class="img-indent" /><br />
                                                              <a href="#" class="link2"><strong>News</strong></a> <br />
                                                                <ul class="boxlist">
                                                                   <li>Link to News Story</li>
                                                                   <li>Link to News Story 2</li>
                                                                   <li>Link to News Story 3</li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                               </div>
                                                            <div class="col-3">
                                                                <img alt="" src="images/1page_img2.jpg" class="img-indent" /><br />
                                                              <a href="#" class="link2"><strong>Information</strong> <br />
                                                               &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;mau <span>rillus</span> </a>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-3">
                                                                <img alt="" src="images/1page_img3.jpg" class="img-indent" /><br />
                                                              <a href="#" class="link2"><strong>Products</strong> <br />
                                                               &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;cumsoci <span>inatot</span> </a>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-4">
                                                                <img alt="" src="images/1page_img4.jpg" class="img-indent" /><br />
                                                              <a href="#" class="link2"><strong>Services</strong> <br />
                                                               &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;us etgnis <span>sriea</span>  </a>
                                                          </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img alt="" src="images/1page_title2.gif" class="title1" /><br />
                        <p><strong>04/18/2009 - 14:53</strong></p>
                        <p class="p"><strong>Lum moleie lacneanrit</strong> lacneanrit maurillus Cum sociis natotibus etgnis disriea jesertas leraen<br />
                        monluslertas lrurtas feugiat maleadabi nunc odgravida atcursus nec, luctus a, locenas tristique orci ac sem. Duis ultricies pharetra magna onec accumsan malesuada nec sit amet er orem </p>
                        <a href="#" class="link">more info</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="link">view comments</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="box1">
                        <div class="border-top">
                            <div class="border-bottom">
                                <div class="border-right">
                                    <div class="border-left">
                                        <div class="corner-top-right">
                                            <div class="corner-top-left">
                                                <div class="corner-bottom-left">
                                                    <div class="corner-bottom-right"> 
                                                        <img alt="" src="images/1page_title7.gif" class="title2" /><br />
                                                        <div class="indent-box">
                                                            <ul class="ul">
                                                                <li><a href="#">Acneanrit</a> maurillus cum sociis </li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Cum sociis</a> natotibus etgnis </li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Natotibus</a> etgnis disriea </li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Egnis</a> disriea jesertas leraen </li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Jesertas</a> leraen monluslertas </li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Leraen monluslertas</a> lrurtas </li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Monluslertas</a> lrurtas feugiat </li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Lrurtas</a> feugiat male</li>
                                                                <li class="last"><a href="#">Feugiat</a> malesuadabi unc </li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>                                     
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <form action="" id="form1">
                    <div class="indent-1">
                        <img alt="" src="images/1page_title8.gif" /><br />
                        <p>Enter your email</p>
                         <p><input type="text" class="input" /><a href="#" class="ok" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit()">ok</a></p>
                        <a href="#" class="link3"> Unsubscribe</a>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box3">
            <div class="border-top3">
                <div class="corner-top-right3">
                    <div class="corner-top-left3">
                        <div class="indent-box3">
                            <img alt="" src="images/1page_title3.gif" /><br />
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="col-5 maxheight">
                                    <div class="box2 maxheight">
                                        <div class="border-top maxheight">
                                            <div class="border-bottom maxheight">
                                                <div class="border-right maxheight">
                                                    <div class="border-left maxheight">
                                                        <div class="corner-top-right maxheight">
                                                            <div class="corner-top-left maxheight">
                                                                <div class="corner-bottom-left maxheight">
                                                                    <div class="corner-bottom-right maxheight"> 
                                                                        <div class="indent-box">
                                                                            <img alt="" src="images/1page_title4.gif" class="title-1" /><br />
                                                                            <h4>Sed laoreet aliquam lda let aliquam. </h4> 
                                                                            <p>Mauris fermentum dictum gna. Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus dolorap
                                                                            ibus eget element vel, cursus </p>
                                                                            <p>Mauris fermentum dictum gnased </p>
                                                                            <a href="#" class="link3">more info</a>            
                                                                        </div>                                     
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-5 maxheight">
                                    <div class="box2 maxheight">
                                        <div class="border-top maxheight">
                                            <div class="border-bottom maxheight">
                                                <div class="border-right maxheight">
                                                    <div class="border-left maxheight">
                                                        <div class="corner-top-right maxheight">
                                                            <div class="corner-top-left maxheight">
                                                                <div class="corner-bottom-left maxheight">
                                                                    <div class="corner-bottom-right maxheight"> 
                                                                      <div class="indent-box">
                                                                          <img alt="" src="images/1page_title5.gif" class="title-1" /><br />
                                                                          <ul class="p">
                                                                            <li><a href="#">Vivamus eget nibhacilisiaenea</a></li>
                                                                                <li><a href="#">Nec erosestibulum ante ipsum</a></li>
                                                                                <li><a href="#">Faucibus orci luctus et ultrices </a></li>
                                                                                <li><a href="#">Posuere cubilia curae</a></li>
                                                                            <li><a href="#">Suspendisse sollicitudin velit sed </a></li>
                                                                            </ul>
                                                                            <a href="#" class="link3">more info</a>            
                                                                        </div>                                     
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              <div class="col-5 maxheight">
                                    <div class="box2 maxheight">
                                        <div class="border-top maxheight">
                                            <div class="border-bottom maxheight">
                                                <div class="border-right maxheight">
                                                    <div class="border-left maxheight">
                                                        <div class="corner-top-right maxheight">
                                                            <div class="corner-top-left maxheight">
                                                                <div class="corner-bottom-left maxheight">
                                                                    <div class="corner-bottom-right maxheight"> 
                                                                        <div class="indent-box">
                                                                          <img alt="" src="images/1page_title6.gif" class="title-1" /><br />
                                                                            <h4>Ut tellus dolorapibus eget elemeel. </h4> 
                                                                            <p>Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus dolorapibus eget element vel, cursus eleifend, elit. Aenean auctor wisi et </p>
                                                                            <p>Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus  </p>
                                                                            <a href="#" class="link3">more info</a>            
                                                                        </div>                                     
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>   
<div id="footer">
    <div class="bot-left">
        <div class="bot-right">
            <div class="indent-footer">Doggie &nbsp;&copy; 2009 &nbsp;<a href="index-5.html">Privacy Policy</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoever wrote that, take them out back and shoot them. There is no excuse for nesting `<div>`s that deep.

Comment: @Kolink lol.  Rob, you should at least comment out each `</div>` so you know what ends what.  Make it a _little_ easier to read anyway

Comment: haha....that's a template from template monster.  i agree. I just bought it today

Comment: At least you got a lot of divs for your money!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works to add bullets to those elements.

```
.boxlist li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Your bullets are being hidden by your parent divs since by default they appear outside of the list bounding box.  You can either move the bullets to inside the bounding box (shown above) or set a margin-left on them.

Comment: Bill, added .boxlist li {list-style-type:disc;} and it's not working

Comment: Try my update. Adding !important will force this rule to be applied. In your css, list-style-type is being set at the root level elements `#content ul` which are taking precedence. In FireFox you will see the rule you are trying to add being crossed out meaning that it was overriden.

Comment: I now have `.boxlist li {list-style-type:disc !important;}` and it's doing nothing. Crazy....

Comment: Your bullets are hidden under the divs.  You need to add `list-style-position: inside` to your class. See my update.

Comment: Bill, I checked Firefox and it looks like your style is being accepted, but it's not changing the specific elements at all.

Answer (score 0):

To get the immediate `<li>` children, you could do this:

```
$(".boxlist").children();
```

(I assumed you were using jQuery, which I see now that you're probably not doing.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this css for example to adjust. This should help if I understand correctly.

Ex.
 .boxlist li{color:#f1f;}